# Logic Apps: How to process messages from service bus queue during certain time duration?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues

I want to create a logic app which processes items from service bus queue during specific time (say 7 AM to 8 PM EST) and during specific days (Monday to Friday). The queue message has json which needs to be converted to file and send the file to file location. The downstream system is only expecting files during 7 AM to 8 PM EST. Is there way to create service bus queue trigger and configure it to fire during defined day and time? Can this be achieved using Recurrence trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rethink the way you set up the logic app. Instead of using a service bus queue trigger use a [recurrence trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence). You can configure it to run on the times and days you specified.

Then, when it is triggered you can read all non-processed messages using the Service Bus connector. It contains [an operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#get-messages-from-a-queue-(peek-lock)) to read messages from a queue and an operation to [complete the message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#complete-the-message-in-a-queue).

There is no out-of-the-box way to stop the logica app run automatically on a given time. You will need to do that yourself. The way I see you will probably have a loop in which you pull messages from the queue. Inside that you could check the time and stop if it is close to the ending period of the downstream system.